# Query in RAILS taking WAY longer than via Mysql client

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

So I just started with RAILS. I know just enough to be dangerous.

I have a bunch of models doing very simple queries, mostly generated via scaffold. I have a legacy db, and most of it is already rails compatible. Everything has indexes. The DB is not massive, but it is significant.

On one model I simply did a .all and it took forever, of course that table has about 400,000 rows. That being said, it was WAYY faster in Mysql. I took the same table and then tried to get maybe 100 results and it took maybe a few minutes. The same query in mysql took less than a second. When I check the console I see this when it is done:

> Node Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `nodes`.*
>   FROM `nodes` WHERE (`nodes`.`id` =
>   276645) LIMIT 1   CACHE (0.0ms) 
>   SELECT `profiles`.* FROM
>   `profiles` WHERE
>   (`profiles`.`id` = 0)
>   LIMIT 1   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT
>   `points`.* FROM `points`
>   WHERE (`points`.`id` = 19404)
>   LIMIT 1

over and over. When the query wasn't returning back anything (in other words, I had some logic incorrect), it was extremely fast. I think it is not doing "joins" but rather querying individually or something for related models. Ideas?

The model looks something like this:

```
class Trigger < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.table_name() "w_trigger" end
  belongs_to :node
  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :point

  scope :within, lambda{|up,down,left,right| joins(:point).where('`points`.`lat` <= ? AND `points`.`lat` >= ? AND `points`.`lon` <= ? AND `points.`.`lon` >= ?',up,down,left,right)}

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mysql query is probably taking roughly the same amount of time to execute. What you are suffering if Object creation time. Creating 400000 Ruby objects, especially relatively fat objects like ActiveRecord ones, takes a fair amount of time.

What are you really trying to do? You obviously are not trying to render that many objects for a web request. If you are, you would want to only return the specific number of rows you need for that page.

Thus is life in Rails.

Comment: Ahh interesting... I got it down to around 30-40 items... It was much faster this time. Are there any optimizations for larger data sets of around a few hundred? If you are mapping things graphically or geographically... it is useful to grab a bunch of items at once. Is there a way to unbind and bind relationships on the fly to speed things up?

Comment: You should only grab the things you need. Operating on hundreds of objects should be perfectly reasonable. You should definitely have indexes on those columns to make sure you are searching quickly, although I hear having multiple range queries (using >= instead of =) is not helpful, only one of the ranges can use an index.